# Remove border from navbar

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using angularjs material for designing but i stuck at removing border of the navbar list from the md-nav-list.
[image]

[image: image of navbar]

the red line under page one is the line i want to remove 
code is

```
<div layout="row" class="navbar-top" flex >
    <md-input-container class="md-block" md-no-float >
            <md-icon class="material-icons">search</md-icon>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user" placeholder="search.." class="search-bar" >
    </md-input-container>
    <md-nav-bar flex="60" md-no-ink-bar="disableInkBar" md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem"  nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">

            <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">
              Page One
            </md-nav-item>
            <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="#" >
              <md-icon class="material-icons">messages</md-icon>
            </md-nav-item>

          </md-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the border to always be gone, you need to change you `mod-nav-bar`'s `md-no-ink-bar` attribute to be set to `true`, a.k.a  `md-no-ink-bar="true"` instead of `md-no-ink-bar="disableInkBar"`. I'm guessing you saw that setting used in the documentation, but that was probably because they had a variable `disableInkBar` set by an angular controller that they were then using to toggle the border. For you case though, as long as you don't want to turn the border on and off, setting it to `md-no-ink-bar="true"` should do exactly what you want! :)